# How to add new elements to an objects-array using event listener and show it on the html page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, dom

I was trying to make a **todo application**, then I wanted to add new todo using a `form` and an `event listener` but, when I finished the code the app only adds the written text to the `object-array` and doesn't actually add it to the todos list in the html page.

I'll provide a small code down below showing the array, the setup code and the html as well in order to make this question short, but if you want to see the whole application code feel free to check this github's repository: https://github.com/salahmak/Todo-application

You can also check out the live version of the app from this `ngrok` link (i'll keep it live until I fix the problem) : http://7eb95c9a.ngrok.io

The code:

```js
// The array
const todos = [{
  text: 'wake up',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'get some food',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'play csgo',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'play minecraft',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'learn javascript',
  completed: false
}];


//creating p elements and assigning their text content to each "text" property of the "todos" array

todos.forEach(function(todo) {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = todo.text;
  document.querySelector('#todo').appendChild(p);
})
```

```html
<h1>Todos</h1>

<form id="form">
  Add a new todo
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type your first name" name="firstName">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You're missing a `#todo` element in your HTML

Comment: It's easy to know where the error is by looking your devTools console, always debug your code and you will find errors easily. The first answer below is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector('#todo').appendChild(p);` You're appending to a non-existent `#todo` element. Throw in a `<div id="todo"></div>` and it'll work.

Working:

```js
// The array
const todos = [{
    text: 'wake up',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'get some food',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'play csgo',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play minecraft',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'learn javascript',
    completed: false
}];


//creating p elements and assigning their text content to each "text" property of the "todos" array

todos.forEach(function(todo){
        let p = document.createElement('p');
        p.textContent = todo.text;
        document.querySelector('#todo').appendChild(p);
    })
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Todos</h1>

    <form id="form">
        Add a new todo
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type your first name" name="firstName">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    
    <div id="todo"></div>

    <script src="todo-app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that the `#todos` element is not present in your HTML, which means there is no "destination" for `todos` data to be displayed in your page.

As an improvment to your app, consider defining a reusuable function like `updateView()` that updates the contents of the `#todo` element to display the current data in the `todos` array. In you app, that could be called:

1. after submission of your form, to display newly added todos
2. on load, to display inital data

One way to implement this is as follows:

```js
// The array
const todos = [{
  text: 'wake up',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'get some food',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'play csgo',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'play minecraft',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'learn javascript',
  completed: false
}];


/* Reusable function that updates the view container with current
data in todos array */
function updateView() {

  const container = document.getElementById("todo");

  /* Clear list */
  container.innerHTML = "";

  /* Populate list with current todos data */
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = todo.text;
    container.appendChild(p);
  });
}

const form = document.getElementById("form");

/* Add form submit event handler to add actual todo to list(s) */
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {

  /* Prevent default "page reload" form submit behavior */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* Extract text from input field */
  const text = form.querySelector('input[name="firstName"]').value;
  
  /* Add new todo item to todos array (model) */
  todos.push({
    text: text,
    completed: false
  });

  /* Update container with added todo data */
  updateView();
});

/* Populate container with inital data */
updateView();
```

```html
<h1>Todos</h1>

<form id="form">
  Add a new todo
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type your first name" name="firstName">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<!-- Add a DOM element that contains the actual display list -->
<div id="todo">
</div>
```

Comment: it was just a div element and i forgot to add it to this post lol u can check the github to see

Comment: No problems - just had a look at the gh repo and see that you have the todo there :)

Comment: so what is the problem after all ?

Comment: looks like you haven't defined `addTask()`